# Latency issue in Spark DataFrame distinct count

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing a distinct count key on spark dataframe, It is taking too much time ~ 7 to 8 seconds for 6k records partitioned across more than 180 partitions. I can see 80% of time is consumed in serialization and the shuffle, compute time is very less.

```
 val df = jdbcTable.filter($"COL" === "FILTER_CONDITION")
        .map(row => ((row.getInt(0), row.getString(1)), s"${row.getInt(0)},${row.getString(1)},${row.getLong(2)},${row. /*getDecimal*/ getString(3)},${row.getString(4)}"))
        .toDF("COL1", "Message")
val df2 = tranformKeyedDF(df,df.select($"COL1").distinct.count)



  def tranformKeyedDF(keyedDF: DataFrame, repartitionCount: Int) =
    {
      import keyedDF.sqlContext.implicits._

      val df = keyedDF match {
        case keyedDF if (!keyedDF.rdd.isEmpty()) =>
          {
            val repartitionedDF = keyedDF.repartition(repartitionCount, $"Col1")
              .select($"Message")
              .select(expr("(split(Message, ','))[0]").cast("Int").as("Tag1"),
                expr("(split(Message, ','))[1]").cast("String").as("Tag2"),
                expr("(split(Message, ','))[2]").cast("Long").as("Tag3"),
                expr("(split(Message, ','))[3]").cast("String").as("Tag4"),
                expr("(split(Message, ','))[4]").cast("String").as("Tag5"))
              .sortWithinPartitions($"Tag3", $"Tag4")

            repartitionedDF

          }

        case keyedDF if (keyedDF.rdd.isEmpty()) =>
          {
            val repartitionedDF = keyedDF.repartition(1, $"Col1")
              .select($"Message")
              .select(expr("(split(Message, ','))[0]").cast("Int").as("Tag1"),
                expr("(split(Message, ','))[1]").cast("String").as("Tag2"),
                expr("(split(Message, ','))[2]").cast("Long").as("Tag3"),
                expr("(split(Message, ','))[3]").cast("String").as("Tag4"),
                expr("(split(Message, ','))[4]").cast("String").as("Tag5"))

            repartitionedDF
          }
      }

      df

    }
```

[image]

Is there any better API for counting distinct key on dataframe with less shuffle in terms of latency. I am using spark 1.6.

Comment: What is tranformKeyedDF ?

Comment: @ datmannz, tranformKeyedDF is a method for transforming df DataFrame, actually I am partitioning df by the distinct key count in tranformKeyedDF method

Comment: Possible for u to post the code for tranaformKeyedDF? I believe some extra shuffling is happening there.

Comment: @ datmannz, tranformKeyedDF  copied in the post, but tranformKeyedDF   is getting invoke later, Distinct Count is executing first

Comment: I suspect its not the distinct method, but "repartition(repartitionCount, $"Col1")" is taking a lot of time since it has to hash shuffle the entire dataset. 

what is the size of the dataset? and where are u running it - yarn? on AWS?

Comment: i m running on hortonworks on prem yarn

Comment: To be sure, can you remove tranformKeyedDF and run the code again.

Something like:
val df2 = df.select($"COL1").distinct.count

Comment: @ datmannz, I can see in the spark UI job with the line number pointing to distinct count code taking 7 to 8 sec.